# KEDA - no pods are scaling

Tags: python, kubernetes, autoscaling, hpa, keda

I am trying to create a KEDA scaled job based on RabbitMQ queue trigger but encountered an issue when pods are not scaling at all.

I have created a following Scaled job and lined up messages in the queue but no pods are created. I see this **message: Scaling is not performed because triggers are not active**

What could be reason that pods are not scaling at all? Thanks for help.

And in Keda logs I see:

```
2021-12-29T13:50:19.738Z    INFO    scalemetrics    Checking if ScaleJob Scalers are active {"ScaledJob": "celery-rabbitmq-scaledjob-2", "isActive": false, "maxValue": 0, "MultipleScalersCalculation": ""}
2021-12-29T13:50:19.738Z    INFO    scaleexecutor   Scaling Jobs    {"scaledJob.Name": "celery-rabbitmq-scaledjob-2", "scaledJob.Namespace": "sandbox-dev", "Number of running Jobs": 0}
2021-12-29T13:50:19.738Z    INFO    scaleexecutor   Scaling Jobs    {"scaledJob.Name": "celery-rabbitmq-scaledjob-2", "scaledJob.Namespace": "sandbox-dev", "Number of pending Jobs ": 0}
```

--

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledJob
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"keda.sh/v1alpha1","kind":"ScaledJob","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"celery-rabbitmq-scaledjob-2","namespace":"sandbox-dev"},"spec":{"failedJobsHistoryLimit":5,"jobTargetRef":{"activeDeadlineSeconds":3600,"backoffLimit":6,"completions":1,"parallelism":5,"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"command":["/bin/bash","-c","CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://$RABBITMQ_USERNAME:$RABBITMQ_PASSWORD@rabbitmq.sandbox-dev.svc.cluster.local:5672
      celery worker -A test_data.tasks.all --loglevel=info -c 1 -n
      worker.all"],"env":[{"name":"APP_CFG","value":"test_data.config.dev"},{"name":"C_FORCE_ROOT","value":"true"},{"name":"RABBITMQ_USERNAME","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"rabbitmq-user","name":"develop"}}},{"name":"RABBITMQ_PASSWORD","valueFrom":{"secretKeyRef":{"key":"rabbitmq-pass","name":"develop"}}}],"image":"767487149142.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test-data-celery:DEV-2021.12.27.0","imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent","lifecycle":{"postStart":{"exec":{"command":["/bin/sh","-c","echo
      startup \u003e\u003e
      /tmp/startup.log"]}},"preStop":{"exec":{"command":["/bin/sh","-c","echo
      shutdown \u003e\u003e
      /tmp/shutdown.log"]}}},"name":"celery-backend","resources":{"limits":{"cpu":"1700m","memory":"3328599654400m"},"requests":{"cpu":"1600m","memory":"3Gi"}},"securityContext":{"allowPrivilegeEscalation":false,"privileged":false,"readOnlyRootFilesystem":false},"terminationMessagePath":"/tmp/termmsg.log","terminationMessagePolicy":"File","volumeMounts":[{"mountPath":"/tmp","name":"temp"},{"mountPath":"/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount","name":"default-token-s7vl6","readOnly":true}]}]}}},"maxReplicaCount":100,"pollingInterval":5,"rolloutStrategy":"gradual","successfulJobsHistoryLimit":5,"triggers":[{"metadata":{"host":"amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq.sandbox-dev.svc.cluster.local:5672/vhost","mode":"QueueLength","queueName":"celery","value":"1"},"type":"rabbitmq"}]}}
  creationTimestamp: '2021-12-29T13:11:15Z'
  finalizers:
    - finalizer.keda.sh
  generation: 3
  managedFields:
    - apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:finalizers: {}
        f:spec:
          f:jobTargetRef:
            f:template:
              f:metadata:
                .: {}
                f:creationTimestamp: {}
          f:scalingStrategy: {}
        f:status:
          .: {}
          f:conditions: {}
      manager: keda
      operation: Update
      time: '2021-12-29T13:11:15Z'
    - apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
        f:spec:
          .: {}
          f:failedJobsHistoryLimit: {}
          f:jobTargetRef:
            .: {}
            f:activeDeadlineSeconds: {}
            f:backoffLimit: {}
            f:completions: {}
            f:template:
              .: {}
              f:spec:
                .: {}
                f:containers: {}
          f:maxReplicaCount: {}
          f:pollingInterval: {}
          f:rolloutStrategy: {}
          f:successfulJobsHistoryLimit: {}
          f:triggers: {}
      manager: kubectl-client-side-apply
      operation: Update
      time: '2021-12-29T13:11:15Z'
    - apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:spec:
          f:jobTargetRef:
            f:parallelism: {}
      manager: node-fetch
      operation: Update
      time: '2021-12-29T13:37:11Z'
  name: celery-rabbitmq-scaledjob-2
  namespace: sandbox-dev
  resourceVersion: '222981509'
  selfLink: >-
    /apis/keda.sh/v1alpha1/namespaces/sandbox-dev/scaledjobs/celery-rabbitmq-scaledjob-2
  uid: 9013295a-6ace-48ba-96d3-8810efde1b35
status:
  conditions:
    - message: ScaledJob is defined correctly and is ready to scaling
      reason: ScaledJobReady
      status: 'True'
      type: Ready
    - message: Scaling is not performed because triggers are not active
      reason: ScalerNotActive
      status: 'False'
      type: Active
    - status: Unknown
      type: Fallback
spec:
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 5
  jobTargetRef:
    activeDeadlineSeconds: 3600
    backoffLimit: 6
    completions: 1
    parallelism: 1
    template:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
      spec:
        containers:
          - command:
              - /bin/bash
              - '-c'
              - >-
                CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://$RABBITMQ_USERNAME:$RABBITMQ_PASSWORD@rabbitmq.sandbox-dev.svc.cluster.local:5672
                celery worker -A test_data.tasks.all --loglevel=info -c 1
                -n worker.all
            env:
              - name: APP_CFG
                value: test_data.config.dev
              - name: C_FORCE_ROOT
                value: 'true'
              - name: RABBITMQ_USERNAME
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    key: rabbitmq-user
                    name: develop
              - name: RABBITMQ_PASSWORD
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    key: rabbitmq-pass
                    name: develop
            image: >-
              111.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test-data-celery:DEV-2021.12.27.0
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            lifecycle:
              postStart:
                exec:
                  command:
                    - /bin/sh
                    - '-c'
                    - echo startup >> /tmp/startup.log
              preStop:
                exec:
                  command:
                    - /bin/sh
                    - '-c'
                    - echo shutdown >> /tmp/shutdown.log
            name: celery-backend
            resources:
              limits:
                cpu: 1700m
                memory: 3328599654400m
              requests:
                cpu: 1600m
                memory: 3Gi
            securityContext:
              allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
              privileged: false
              readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
            terminationMessagePath: /tmp/termmsg.log
            terminationMessagePolicy: File
            volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /tmp
                name: temp
              - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
                name: default-token-s7vl6
                readOnly: true
  maxReplicaCount: 100
  pollingInterval: 5
  rolloutStrategy: gradual
  scalingStrategy: {}
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 5
  triggers:
    - metadata:
        host: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq.sandbox-dev.svc.cluster.local:5672/vhost
        mode: QueueLength
        queueName: celery
        value: '1'
      type: rabbitmq
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mode may not work in some cases.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67319005/2777988)

Try changing

```
- metadata:
    host: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq.sandbox-dev.svc.cluster.local:5672/vhost
    mode: QueueLength
    queueName: celery
    value: '1'
```

to

```
- metadata:
    host: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq.sandbox-dev.svc.cluster.local:5672/vhost
    queueName: files
    queueLength: '1'
```